# How to remove scrolling inside iOS from the web view of swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, touch

I am currently doing a webview. My problem is that I want to prevent iOS from scrolling inside. The scrolling I speak is not the scrolling created in the Web view, but the bouncing scrolling that occurs when you touch up or up by touching down.

It doesn't work for me.

```swift
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        WKWebView.scrollView.bounces = false

        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
        URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

...
```

```swift
class WebViewController: ... UIScrollViewDelegate {
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        mainWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
        mainWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
...
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
        }
    }
```

I'm using **WKWebView**

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was where the function was executed. This function does not work when executed in the `LoadView` function. You must run it in the `ViewDidLoad` function.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        WKWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
```